# How to use torch.utils.tensorboard.SummaryWriter from the last interrupted events

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

[image]

As in this picture, if I want to add scalar from ***events.out.tfevents***, but not create a new one.

How can I set the params int this code:

```
SummaryWriter(self, log_dir=None, comment='', purge_step=None, max_queue=10,
             flush_secs=120, filename_suffix='')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run it the same way (e.g. `log_dir` has to be the same, `tensorboard` in your case).

You have to remember to use **next global step when adding scalar though**.

First run, assume it crashed at `9`th step:

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

writer = SummaryWriter("my_dir")
x = range(10)
for i in x:
    writer.add_scalar("y=x", i, i)
writer.close()
```

If you want to continue writing to this event file, you have to move last parameter global step by `10`:

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

writer = SummaryWriter("my_dir")
x = range(10)
for i in x:
    writer.add_scalar("y=x", i, i + 10) # start from step 10
writer.close()
```

Running first file, followed by the second one and opening `tensorboard` via `tensorboard --logdir my_dir` would give you:

[image: tensorboard_restart]